# Faster alternative to multivariate LOESS?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, predictive-models, smoothing

I want to make predictions by creating a smooth response surface to 2 variables.  I get good results using R's loess() function, but with 10 million observations, it is far too slow.  Are there any other smoothing algorithms that would provide similar results at a lower computational cost?

Comment: [GAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_additive_model)?

Comment: Which smoother would you recommend using with GAM?

Comment: The default thin-plate spline assuming your variables are isotropic (or you expect the "roughness" in each dimension to be similar)... on my computer, `gam`'s execution time with the default smoother appears roughly linear in the # of observations (10^4...10^6) and I'd expect it to take about 1 hour for 10^7 observations.

Comment: One suggestion is to consider something like ACE or perhaps AVAS to try to get an additive model (see package `ace`). Then once you have a transformation for Y to approximate additivity, if the fit from ACE doesn't grab you (it's not always sufficiently smooth for me) you can do loess in each variable separately, or use splines, or whatever other univariate smoother takes your fancy